# Make django templates strict

Tags: django, django-templates, django-errors

In a django template, a call to `{{ var }}` will silently fail if `var` is undefined. That makes templates hard to debug. Is there a setting I can switch so django will throw an exception in this case?

The only hint at a solution I've found online is http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine/browse_thread/thread/86a5b12ff868038d and that sounds awfully hacky.

Comment: Method 1 in your specified link looks good. Since, custom template tags are legitimate option for extending template functionality.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Django<=1.9**

Set `TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID = 'DEBUG WARNING: undefined template variable [%s] not found'` in your `settings.py`.

See docs:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#template-string-if-invalid

**Django>=1.10**

Set `string_if_invalid = 'DEBUG WARNING: undefined template variable [%s] not found'` template option in your `settings.py`.

See docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/templates/#module-django.template.backends.django

Also read:
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#invalid-template-variables

Comment: `TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID = '%s'` would be more appropriate as that will print the variable name that isn't defined instead of some random text. However read the admonition box on the second link very carefully. This is really for one-off debugging instances, *not* something you should just leave on all the time in development.

Comment: The TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID settings will help with finding invalid variables, when we attempt to print them in a template, but if the variable is used in an if-statement or as the collection in a for-loop, there is no help to be found... Is there any way to catch these cases as well?

Comment: Is there a way to raise an exception if a variable is undefined?

Comment: Please update your answer to take into account django 1.10+ where `TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID` has been deprecated.

Comment: 'OPTIONS': {
'string_if_invalid': 'Invalid varialbe!',
         }

Answer (score 4):

This hack from [djangosnippets](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/646/) will raise an exception when an undefined variable is encountered in a template.

```
# settings.py
class InvalidVarException(object):
    def __mod__(self, missing):
        try:
            missing_str = unicode(missing)
        except:
            missing_str = 'Failed to create string representation'
        raise Exception('Unknown template variable %r %s' % (missing, missing_str))
    def __contains__(self, search):
        if search == '%s':
            return True
        return False

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID = InvalidVarException()
```

Comment: This does not seem to detect undefined foobar in `{% if foobar %}` or `{% for foo in foobar %}`

Comment: After upgrade from 1.9.x > 1.10.1 I get: `?: (templates.E002) 'string_if_invalid' in TEMPLATES OPTIONS must be a string but got: <ia_django.settings.local.InvalidVarException object at 0x10566a490> (InvalidVarException).` So this hack doesn't work any more.

Comment: @allcaps  what if you inherit it from `basestring` or `unicode`?

Comment: @utapyngo I silenced the system check: `SILENCED_SYSTEM_CHECKS = ['templates.E002']`.

Comment: Another way to do it without silencing system checks is: Changing superclass of InvalidVarException to unicode instead of object, setting parameter to InvalidVarException("%s") instead. Btw it works, but I am not getting correct line of template where it crashes anymore. Any way around this?

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the django-shouty-templates app: https://pypi.org/project/django-shouty-templates/

> This app applies a monkeypatch which forces Django’s template language to error far more loudly about invalid assumptions. Specifically:
>
> - `chef` would raise an exception if the variable were called `sous_chef`.
> - `chef.can_add_cakes` would raise an exception if `can_add_cakes` was not a valid attribute/property/method of chef
>
> It ain’t compile time safety, but it’s better than silently swallowing errors because you forgot something!

Comment: Thank you for this hint!

Answer (score 1):

I use this [pytest-django config](https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html?highlight=FAIL_INVALID_TEMPLATE_VARS#fail-on-template-vars-fail-for-invalid-variables-in-templates):

```
[pytest]
FAIL_INVALID_TEMPLATE_VARS = True
```

This way I get an exception if I run the tests.

Answer (score -2):

That's part of the design. It allows you to provide defaults and switch based on whether or not a variable exists in the context. It also allows templates to be very flexible and promotes re-usability of templates instead of a strict "each view must have it's own template" approach.

More to the point, templates are not really supposed to be "debugged". The idea is to put as much of your logic as possible *outside* the template, in the views or models. If you want to figure out why a variable that's supposed to be passed to the context isn't, the place to debug that is in your view. Just drop `import pdb;pdb.set_trace()` somewhere before your view returns and poke around.

Comment: @Marcin: I'm speaking in the sense of Django's perspective. If you're relying on template debug errors in development for things not related to fumble-fingering a templatetag or other simple mistakes, you've likely got too much logic in your template.

Comment: Well, that's a matter of opinion :) But it is the 'Django Opinion', and it if matters enough to you, use a different template engine! I do, for this reason among others.

Comment: @AdamKG, what other engine can use strict templates? Goes Jinja2 have that feature?

Comment: @Eldamir: apparently so http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3983581/raise-an-exception-in-jinja-if-we-passed-in-a-variable-that-is-not-present-in-th