# .items not working on defaultdict in Django template

Tags: python, django, dictionary, django-templates

I can't get .items to work in my Django template:

copy and paste from my CBV's get_context_data:

```
    context['data'] = assertion_dict
    context['dataitems'] = assertion_dict.items()

    return context
```

copy and paste from my template:

```
  <h3>data dump</h3>
  {{data}}

  <h3>dataitems</h3>
  {% for key, value in dataitems %}
     {{ key }}: {{ value }} <br/>
  {% endfor %}

  <h3>data.items</h3>
  {% for key, value in data.items %}
     {{ key }}: {{ value }} <br/>
  {% endfor %}

  <h3>Not found test</h3>
  {{ i_dont_exist }}
```

output:

```
**data dump**
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {<BadgeType: Talent>: [<BadgeAssertion: Blender Blue Belt>], <BadgeType: Achievement>: [<BadgeAssertion: MyBadge#1>, <BadgeAssertion: MyBadge#1>, <BadgeAssertion: MyBadge#2>], <BadgeType: Award>: [<BadgeAssertion: Copy of Copy of Blenbade>]})

**dataitems**
Talent: [<BadgeAssertion: Blender Blue Belt>]
Achievement: [<BadgeAssertion: MyBadge#1>, <BadgeAssertion: MyBadge#1>, <BadgeAssertion: MyBadge#2>]
Award: [<BadgeAssertion: Copy of Copy of Blenbade>]

**data.items**

**Not found test**
DEBUG WARNING: undefined template variable [i_dont_exist] not found
```

Why isn't the second version working, where I use data.items in my template?

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong with your first example template. Check for typos or accidental reassignment of `context['data']` or deletion of items from `assertion_dict`.

Comment: To rule out typos and other problems, I sent both in the context at the same time, and copy/pasted the view, template, and resulting HTML output.  Question is updated with this info.

Comment: I would a) add a dump of `{{ data }}` somewhere in your template - Python dicts stringify in a reasonable way, and that should help verify whether or not your `data` variable contains what you expect - and b) temporarily set your `TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID` setting as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8990344/2337736

Comment: Added ``{{data}}`` dump

Comment: Added string_if_invalid

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a [known issue in Django](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/16335): you cannot iterate over a `defaultdict` in a template. The docs suggest that the best way [to handle this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/language/#variables) is to convert your `defaultdict` to a `dict` before passing it to the template:

```
context['data'] = dict(assertion_dict)
```

The reason it doesn't work, by the way, is that when you call `{{ data.items }}` in your template, Django will first attempt to find `data['items']`, and then `data.items`. The `defaultdict` will return a default value for the former, so Django will not attempt the latter, and you end up trying to loop over the default value instead of the dict.